# What /testfor command do I need to check the value of a scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've created a dummy objective, 'time' and have a 1 second repeater clock adding 1 to the score for `@a` every second. I then have a command block that will execute a `/testfor` to check when the score '600' is met and a comparator will light up a redstone lamp to say when 10mins has passed. What command would the `/testfor` command block need?

Answer (score 1):

This command should be what you want:

```
/testfor @a[score_time_min=600]
```

This will only give a weak output, so make sure to have a repeater after the comparator.